# How do I display images saved in a folder on my server alongside data from mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, image

I have created a database with id, description, keywords, year and location. I'm working on creating a page that will populate with all uploaded to my database. To be clear, I have saved uploaded images into a folder on my server, not my database.

I can manage to get a table with the fields of my database but now I'm trying to get my images that correspond with the image id into the table.

I believe I need to do something like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM insert image path here
```

I've tried out different things and can't get anything to work.

P.S. I'm using MAMP and not actually uploading this to a server at the moment.

Below is my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php

    error_reporting(-1);

    // connection 
    // TODO:secure connection details 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "name";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "archive";
    $dirname = "uploads/";

    // Create db connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // stop if failed
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Connection failed: " .
            mysqli_connect_error() .
            " " . mysqli_connect_errno());
    }

    // I think I need to call the img before the data 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $target_file = "uploads/img_".$id.".jpg";"

    // TODO: fix SQL injection 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM photo_data"; // give me everything from photodata table ordered desc

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (!$result){
        die("Database query failed." . mysqli_error($conn));
    } else { 
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><th>id</th><th>uniqueid</th><th>description</th><th>keywords</th><th>year</th><th>location</th><th>target file</th></tr>";

        //building row by adding values
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            //building columns 
            foreach ($row as $key => $value) { 
                echo "<td>",$value,"</td>";
            }
            // I think I need to add my images in the section above 
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the only issue i see is not outputting the HTML for displaying an image- right?

Comment: @Dagon That's the only issue you see? I see at least 3 issues in just one line: `$query = "SELECT * FROM $target_file = "uploads/img_".$id.".jpg";"`

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't save your images in the database, but instead on the server, you don't have to prepare a SQL query for this. What you actually need to do is look in your filesystem to find that specific image. From what I understand is that you want to show the image in a table. You could do that like this:

```
$pathToImage = "uploads/img_".$id.".jpg";
echo '<td><img src="'.$pathToImage.'">';
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for your help!